# Proper way to save Jmeter Results to csv - how to finalize results file

Tags: jmeter

I do the same scenario that was already described in other topics not at once: I'm trying to save Jmeter results to database from csv file.

I have an Aggregate Report listener that saves results to csv file, and everything is OK here. 
I also added TearDown Thread Group to my scenario that gets strings from this csv file (by CSV DataSet config) and processes it to database. This part also works fine with static CSV.

Two problems here:

1. Aggregate Report listener is added on the top level of scenario. So, it adds all samplers from TearDown group to results file as well. So, it's like a recursion: if I do teardown until end of result file, I'll never reach the end, as every new iteration adds some new rows.
2. At the moment when CSV dataset config takes csv file, it's still in memory only and not finalized to disk. So, file is just empty. How to tell Jmeter that it should write the content from memory to a file and close input stream?

Any ideas how to solve it?

I know that I can move Listener into threads, but in this case I have to duplicate it for every thread group. It's always better to have one listener in one place as I can potentially change its settings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a JMeter Property **jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush** defaulting to **false**

```
# AutoFlush on each line written in XML or CSV output
# Setting this to true will result in less test results data loss in case of Crash
# but with impact on performances, particularly for intensive tests (low or no pauses)
# Since JMeter 2.10, this is false by default
#jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

You can amend its value by setting it to **true** so JMeter will write down each single line of results into the file and closing the file once done. It can be done in [2 ways](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization):

1. Permanent: add the following line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

   You will need to restart JMeter to pick the change up
2. Ad-hoc: pass the property via [`-J` command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true -n -t .....
   ```

Comment: Parsed the whole jmeter.properties many times, including saveservice parameters, but missed autoflush parameter as it was somehow removed from commented section. Thank you so much, Dmitri! As usual, the most valuable and the fastest answer from you in #jmeter thread. Can't imagine how could I find it without you. You rock!

Comment: So, I solved a problem with empty file, but still don't know how to remove tearDown samplers from csv results file. I know the workaround, so it's not really critical. But maybe you also can suggest something.